# why html action link does not pass the null Id value when use an id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I have used an html action link below

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Book Now", "EnquiryForCruise", "Cruise", new { sid = "stackoverflow" })
```

it navigate to correct controller action result but with null id value
path is `localhost:15777/Cruise/EnquiryForCruise?Length=6`

my controller is below

```
  public ActionResult EnquiryForCruise(string sid)
  {

     return View();
  }
//in here id value is null
```

I have worked with this before and those worked fine. I don't have idea why is this.hope your help.

Comment: please, i can see your code in controller, i can help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this :

```
@Html.ActionLink("Book Now", "EnquiryForCruise", "Cruise", new { sid = "stackoverflow" }, null)
```

Comment: Why should he try this?

Comment: thanx it is working.Is it a must to use `null` after `id`

Comment: The Length=6 is coming from an attempt to serialize a string object. Your code is running this ActionLink method:
public static string ActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)

Comment: but it worked fine for me before.I used it below
`@Html.ActionLink("Select", "CruiseResult", "Cruise", new { selectId = @item.mainID + "|" + @item.farecode + "," + @item.category }, new { @class = "anu" })`

Comment: anyway, thanx for the help

Comment: A simple code dump without any explanation usually is a rather poor answer in my opinion, because it does not teach anything.

Answer (score 2):

There currently is no overload for the ActionLink that takes the text, Action Name, Controller Name, and route parameters. You are missing the Html Attributes.

Try the below:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Book Now", "EnquiryForCruise", "Cruise", new { sid = "stackoverflow" }, null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your routes in RegisterRoutes in Global.asax. See [ASP.NET Routing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx)